# How to parse through a string of STDIN word by word in C

Tags: c, scanf

I would like to read standard input of a command and its argument in a C program, for instance:

ATTACK 50 30

I would like my program to parse through the input using whitespace and assign each word to a variable but right now I would just like to print each word. However, when I tried the program only returned ATTACK and not ATTACK 50 30.

I tried:

```
int main(){

    // Grid size declaration //
    int *x, *y;
    char command[20];

    char user_input[100];
    scanf("%s", user_input);
    printf("%s", user_input);

    return 0;
}
```

As I said I used ATTACK 50 30 as my STDIN but my printf function only returned ATTACK. I thought of maybe using a while loop to keep scanning until the character interpreted is the return key (which I believe in this case would just be the null character?). I tried it using the code below:

```
int main(){

    // Grid size declaration //
    int *x, *y;
    char command[20];

    char user_input[100];
        while(scanf("%s", user_input)!="\0"){
    scanf("%s", user_input);
    printf("%s", user_input);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

This did not work, the error produced declared I was comparing a pointer to an integer.

Comment: `while(scanf("%s", user_input)!="\0") ...` -- `scanf()` does not return a string, and you cannot compare a string with `!=`.

Comment: scanf returns a count of the number of things it read, in your case it will either be 0 or 1

Comment: scanf(" %[^\n]", user_input);

Comment: @Abhi Rai,  Save time,.. Enable all warnings to rapidly see `scanf("%s", user_input)!="\0"` is a problem.

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea `scanf(" %[^\n]", user_input);` without a _width_, is worse than `gets()`.  That also fails to read a line of only `'\n"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think getline will do the job better.

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea `getline()` is quite good, yet it is _non-standard_.  `fgets()` is a compromise  / good solution for portable code to build a better `get_a_line()` function.  What is _best_, depends on additional code requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with `stdin` it would probably be a better idea to utilize the `fgets` function in lieu of the `scanf` function, and then parse the inputted line of data utilizing the [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) string function.

Utilizing that strategy, following is a snippet of code allowing for the parsing of entered text where each word or data group is identified.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 64

int main()
{

    char line[MAX + 1];
    const char delim[2] = " ";
    char * wd;

    printf("Enter some text or type \"quit\" to end: ");

    while (fgets(line, MAX, stdin))
    {
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = ' ';   /* Replace newline character at the end with a space */
        wd = strtok(line, delim);

        while (wd != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(wd, "quit") == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("%s\n", wd);
            wd = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        printf("Enter some text or type \"quit\" to end: ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Testing out this code utilizing your text example yielded the following terminal output.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/ParseWord/bin/Release$ ./ParseWord 
Enter some text or type "quit" to end: ATTACK 50 30
ATTACK
50
30
Enter some text or type "quit" to end: quit
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/ParseWord/bin/Release$
```

This is just a springboard from where you might go, but test that out and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: `line[strlen(line) - 1]` is UB should the first character read is a _null character_.  No likely, yet possible and a hacker exploit.

Comment: Spoken as if from a true hacker at heart. Perhaps `line[strcspn (line, '\n')] = ' ';` instead? Or better, just add `'\n'` to `delim`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Your `strcspn` variant runs into trouble if the line entered is longer than `MAX`: You don't get an `\n` in `line`, and hence overwrite the terminator with a space... adding `\n` to `delim` looks good to me (but will hack a word straddling the `MAX` boundary in two). This can be surprisingly tricky if you want to cover all the bases...

Comment: @DevSolar - yes, this presumes the line fits in the buffer. If the line exceeds the buffer size, then you won't be trimming a `'\n'` anyway `:)`